# I have no idea why this is not working

Tags: java

I made this on Java for Euler, and it just keeps printing 0 over and over again. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, help please?

```
class Euler 
{

  public static void main (String[]args) 
  {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int f = 0;
    int palindrome = 0;
    boolean run = true;
    while (run == true) {
      for (int f4 = 999; f4 >= 100; f4--) {
        for (int f5 = f4; f5 >= 100; f5--) {
          palindrome = f4 * f5;
          f = (palindrome % 10);
          e = (palindrome % 100 - f);
          d = (palindrome % 1000 - e);
          c = (palindrome % 10000 - d);
          b = (palindrome % 100000 - c);
          a = (palindrome % 1000000 - b);
          if (a == 0) {
            if ((b == f) && (c == e)) {
              run = false;
            }
          } else {
            if ((a == f) && (b == e) && (c == d)) {
              run = false;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    int[] nums = new int[1];
    nums[0] = palindrome;
  {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
  }
}
  }
}
```

It's supposed to figure out the largest palindrome made of the product of two three digit numbers.

Comment: Use a debugger or put printf statements in to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop is **never** entered. When you say,

```
for (int f4 = 999; f4 == 100; f4--) {
```

`999` is not `==` 100, so the loop is skipped. I think you wanted

```
for (int f4 = 999; f4 >= 100; f4--) {
```

And the same issue with your next loop.

```
for (int f5 = f4; f5 >= 100; f5--) { // <-- not == 100
```

Comment: Isn't the loop entered exactly once?

Comment: I'm such a moron I have that problem ALL THE TIME and I still don't remember it.

Comment: Now it's just giving me 10000

Comment: No, its a for loop. Do loops are entered and then evaluated, so they will run once or more times.